# How to prevent fullcalendar "moreLink" popover to close when click outside?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, fullcalendar, fullcalendar-6

I am using FullCalendar v6 in nextjs, and it has a built-in feature where it puts the remaining events in a popover when there are too many events, which are shown by clicking "more." My question is, how can I prevent the popover from closing when I click outside of it?

Answer (score 0):

To prevent the popover from closing when clicking outside of it, you can use the interaction object in FullCalendar. Specifically, you can set the enabled property to false for the popover type. This way, the popover won't close when clicking outside of it.

Example below:

```
import { Calendar } from '@fullcalendar/react';
import interactionPlugin from '@fullcalendar/interaction';

const MyCalendarComponent = () => {
  const handleEventClick = (info) => {
    // Your event click logic here
  };

  return (
    <Calendar
      plugins={[interactionPlugin]}
      events={[
        // your event data here
      ]}
      eventClick={handleEventClick}
      eventPopover={{
        enabled: true,
        // By default, clicking outside of the popover will close it.
        // To prevent this, set the interaction.enabled property to false.
        interaction: {
          enabled: false,
        },
      }}
    />
  );
};

export default MyCalendarComponent;
```

You can also refer [this](https://github.com/fullcalendar/fullcalendar/tree/main/packages/interaction)

Comment: Thanks for answering Shivaji, Eventpopover is not in v6 and i want to prevent moreLinkClick popover to close when click outside